# Cannot display all the results in a M2M relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Currently, I have the following entity relationship model :

**Table relationship**

```
 ------------          -----------------           ------
| Objective | ------- | Objective_Task | ---------| Task |
 ------------          -----------------           ------
```

and I am trying to display the results as in the following table

```
| id  |        Task        |   Task status |     Objective      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  Set up drivers    | In progress   | Set up my machine  |
|  2  |  Configure network | In progress   | Set up the network |
|  3  |  Test the network  | In progress   | Set up the network |
```

But the result I get is:

```
| id  |        Task        |   Task status |        Objective          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  Set up drivers    | In progress   | objective.Objective.None  |
|  2  |  Configure network | In progress   | objective.Objective.None  |
|  3  |  Test the network  | In progress   | objective.Objective.None  |
```

Below is the setup of my class models for this entity relationship:

**Objective model**

```
class Objective(models.Model):
    id               = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    objective        = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=60)
    initial_date     = models.DateField(default=timezone.now(), null=False)
    expiration_date  = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['initial_date']
        db_table = 'goal_objective'
```

**Task model**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ACTIVE = 'Active'
    FINALIZED = 'Finalized'

    STATUS = [(ACTIVE, ACTIVE), (FINALIZED, FINALIZED)]

    id           = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    objective    = models.ManyToManyField(Objective)
    task         = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=140)
    status       = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=STATUS, default=ACTIVE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'task_table'
```

This is the code I have used for trying to populate the table.

```
objective_ids = []
qs_current_objectives = Objective.objects.filter(initial_date__gte=date(2020,1,1), expiration_date__lte=date(2020,12,31)).values('id').values_list('id')

for value in qs_current_objectives:
    objective_ids.append(value)    

form = {'task_list': Task.objects.filter(objective__in=objective_ids)}
```

**retrieval.html**

```
{% for task in task_list %}
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>{{task.id}}</td>
         <td>{{task.task}}</td>
         <td>{{task.status}}</td>
         <td>{{task.objective}}</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What did I miss in my models that I cannot reach the name of the objective?

Comment: Have you populated the relationship between the tasks and objectives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you should change to avoid problems in the future.

```
class Objective(models.Model):
    initial_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
```

Note that you pass in the function, not the result of the function call to `default`. If you do what you have, the default will change each time the web server is restarted. Passing the function to default will set the date to the current date.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    objectives    = models.ManyToManyField(Objective, related_name='tasks')
```

Naming the relationship with the plural version of the word makes the code more understandable. Now when you access `task.objectives` you know that it's a collection. `task.objective` makes it seem like there should just be one.

In your view, you don't need to specify that you only want the id. Django will figure that out as long as it's an instance of a Queryset that you're passing along. It'll also only make one query to fetch the data.

```
current_objectives = Objective.objects.filter(
    initial_date__gte=date(2020,1,1),
    expiration_date__lte=date(2020,12,31)
)
tasks = Task.objects.filter(objectives__in=current_objectives).distinct()
form = {'task_list': tasks}
```

Or you can traverse the relationship in the filter.

```
tasks = Task.objects.filter(
    objectives__initial_date__gte=date(2020,1,1),
    objectives__expiration_date__lte=date(2020,12,31),
).distinct()
form = {'task_list': tasks}
```

Then your template should look like:

```
{% for task in task_list %}
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td>{{task.id}}</td>
         <td>{{task.task}}</td>
         <td>{{task.status}}</td>
         <td>{{task.objectives.all}}</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

`task.objectives` (or `task.objective` in your current code) is simply a reference to the Manager instance, not the collection itself. You need to access `.all` to get to the actual data.

Comment: What if instead of using `task.objectives.all` I only want to display the actual name of the objective?

Comment: I found the solution to my last comment, I had to create a custom template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/